# determining unpronounceability

Tags: nlp

I would like to determine whether a given string (eg in English) is pronounceable or not , e.g. using soundex or the like .  Has anyone run across a way to do this?

Examples of unpronounceable: 
'lskjd','xqq','gtmm'

Examples of pronounceable: 
'aabaa','kwerty','smorglebop'

Comment: So you only care about pronounciation even if the word is nonsensical? Or does the word have to mean something too?

Comment: right - only care about pronounceability, word can be nonsense.

Comment: It seems that 3 consonants in a row is surely unpronounceable (at least i can't think of any counterexamples) while there is some small subset of 2-consonant sequences that are pronounceable  , so if I just identify those I suppose anything else will be unronouncable

Comment: Yes. A lack of vowels is another one - can’t think of any words without vowels that can be pronounced. However, talking like this isn’t really data science per-se, it’s just rules based. That’s not the worst thing in the world if it fits your need but there has to be an algorithmic way to solve this.

Comment: @jeremy_rutman (sorry to resurrect a year old thread) - there's a load of 3 consonant clusters. 'thr', 'str', 'ngs', 'rts'. If you're counting 'y' as a potential consonant, you've also got whole words which are only consonants (wry, dry, hymn)

Comment: right - so maybe 4 consonants not counting y , and a list of exceptions for 3 consonants, would do the job